# Get String1 which equals String2 x times?

Tags: java

I have string

```
String str="<td>"
```

And my input `count=5`

Is their any way in which I can get string equal to the counter

output string would be   `str="<td><td><td><td><td>"`

Comment: `str = String.valueOf(count);`

Answer (score 4):

```
String str = "";
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    str = str + "<td>";
}
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: `+=` would look cleaner.

Comment: StringBuilder would be better

Comment: @DrewKennedy Agreed, but what he/she has currently is more understandable for newcomers

Comment: @DrewKennedy I agree, but judging by a question OP is a beginner in java, this syntax is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Create a string as a new character array contraining `count` number of characters. The default character is the null character `\0`. Simply replace all null characters with your required `String`.

```
String str = new String(new char[count]).replace("\0", "<td>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manually create it using `StringBuilder`

```
String str="<td>"
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
   builder.append(str);
}

System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Comment: Faster solution. I would imagine the `StringUtils` class does this internally